# About Linux .so file can't link to the main.cpp file

Tags: c++, c, linux, shared-libraries

I want to create a .so file and let the main.cpp file can call the function where from the .so file.

And these is my files.

```
//aa.h
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void hello();

//hola.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "aa.h"
void hello()
{printf("Hello world!\n");}

//main.cpp
#include "aa.h"
void hello();
int main(){hello();return 0;}
```

---

This is the step below.

Step 1 : Create .so file

```
$ gcc hola.c  -fPIC -shared -o libhola.so
```

It works

Step 2 : Linking the libhola.so to main.cpp and creating a execution file called test

```
$ gcc main.cpp -L. -lhola -o test
```

Just two Step that what I tried.

And the error says：

```
main.cpp:(.text+0x12): undefined reference to `hello()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I had been tried that move the libhola.so to /usr/lib and move the aa.h to /usr/inclued,but not work.

Comment: If i am right, header file should contain `#ifndef SOME_NAME
#define SOME_NAME
// Do something
#endif`

Comment: The C++ language mangles all function names to include the return type and the parameter types.  C language does not do that.   the `gcc` compiler is not for compiling/linking C++ code.  Use `g++` or `gpp` instead.   The get the c++ main program to handle the function `hello` in the library, the header file for the library must have `#ifdef cplusplus { .... }  wrapped around the prototype for the `hello` function.   Note, since the prototype for `hello` is in the header file, do not repeat that prototype in the `main.c` file

Comment: call `ldconfig` from cmd prompt. also check whether `ldconfig -p | grep "hola"` gives some result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are compiling the shared library as a C file (specifically `hello()` function) but you are linking it while compiling a C++ source. You need to make sure `hello()` can be called (i.e. not [*name mangled*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling)) from a C++ executable.

i.e. Add `extern "C"` in your header `aa.h`:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
 extern "C" {
#endif
void hello();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

I'd suggest adding an [*include guard*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) too.

Alternatively, if you rename `main.cpp` to `main.c` then it'd compile fine without this.